# Two linux boxes on same network cannot talk to each other

Tags: networking

I have two Ubuntu machines that cannot talk to each other.

They are sitting next to each other and are plugged into the same switch. They both have static IP addresses and have the same gateway. From my laptop (on a totally different network) I can successfully ping both of them and connect to both of them via ssh and mosh. They can both ping external addresses like google.com and I can ssh out of both of them to resources on separate networks.

They cannot ping each other or connect to each other over ssh. I cannot figure out what the issue would be that would let me connect from the outside but not let them talk to each other.

The only potentially useful thing I've noticed is that the errors are not symmetric:

```
HOST1$ ping HOST2
PING HOST2 (47.51.66.227): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 47.51.66.227 ping statistics ---
18 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

vs

```
HOST2$ ping HOST1
PING HOST1 (47.51.66.226) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 47.51.66.226 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

and for ssh:

```
HOST1$ ssh HOST2
ssh: connect to host 47.51.66.227 port 22: Network is unreachable
```

vs

```
HOST2$ ssh HOST1
ssh: connect to host 47.51.66.226 port 22: No route to host
```

Given the history of these machines, I'm guessing that HOST2 is more likely to have some weird configuration file somewhere, but I'm not sure where to look, as everything I've checked seemed pretty standard. Happy to look at or post anything specific that would be helpful.

Any thoughts on what to fix or even how to better diagnose the issue would be most appreciated!

Edit to include the information requested by Hauke Laging:

```
Host 1$ ip a

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 34:73:5a:fb:23:d6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp4s0f0
    altname ens1f0
    inet 47.51.66.226/30 brd 47.51.66.227 scope global noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2600:6c84:a900:2b2:2543:4ae5:dbb9:a80/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 503165sec preferred_lft 1931sec
    inet6 2600:6c84:a900:2b2:2f52:1e5a:3f1d:d294/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 503165sec preferred_lft 503165sec
    inet6 fe80::1388:32c3:447:42aa/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 34:73:5a:fb:23:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp4s0f1
    altname ens1f1
4: wls5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 14:ab:c5:36:cc:fc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp95s0
    inet 10.42.0.1/24 brd 10.42.0.255 scope global noprefixroute wls5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::da3a:9417:a11e:7f55/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:6c:fc:16:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br-38ee0842186e: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:13:73:72:29 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.28.0.1/16 brd 172.28.255.255 scope global br-38ee0842186e
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:13ff:fe73:7229/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: br-64faac681e43: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:c5:9f:0c:e7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-64faac681e43
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:c5ff:fe9f:ce7/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: vethebf8f2e@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-64faac681e43 state UP group default
    link/ether 2a:74:2a:49:43:17 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::2874:2aff:fe49:4317/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: veth434243b@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-38ee0842186e state UP group default
    link/ether d6:80:53:c8:97:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 5
    inet6 fe80::d480:53ff:fec8:97ab/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: veth5605dd7@if12: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-64faac681e43 state UP group default
    link/ether 1e:32:e1:fa:b7:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::1c32:e1ff:fefa:b714/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
15: vethef9eeac@if14: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-38ee0842186e state UP group default
    link/ether 7a:a7:d2:2c:9b:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 4
    inet6 fe80::78a7:d2ff:fe2c:9ba7/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
17: veth2a8d36c@if16: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-64faac681e43 state UP group default
    link/ether f6:f5:27:c6:8e:fc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 3
    inet6 fe80::f4f5:27ff:fec6:8efc/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
19: vetha420f5d@if18: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-64faac681e43 state UP group default
    link/ether f2:3b:25:fe:6f:eb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 2
    inet6 fe80::f03b:25ff:fefe:6feb/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
21: vethd040ed9@if20: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-64faac681e43 state UP group default
    link/ether 06:d3:36:4f:ce:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 6
    inet6 fe80::4d3:36ff:fe4f:ce80/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
HOST1$ ip r
default via 47.51.66.225 dev eno1 proto static metric 100
10.42.0.0/24 dev wls5 proto kernel scope link src 10.42.0.1 metric 600
47.51.66.224/30 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 47.51.66.226 metric 100
169.254.0.0/16 dev eno1 scope link metric 1000
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-64faac681e43 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1
172.28.0.0/16 dev br-38ee0842186e proto kernel scope link src 172.28.0.1
```

```
HOST1$ ip neigh
10.42.0.176 dev wls5 lladdr d6:63:88:2f:99:18 STALE
172.28.0.2 dev br-38ee0842186e lladdr 02:42:ac:1c:00:02 STALE
10.42.0.36 dev wls5  FAILED
10.42.0.218 dev wls5  FAILED
172.18.0.4 dev br-64faac681e43 lladdr 02:42:ac:12:00:04 REACHABLE
47.51.66.225 dev eno1 lladdr 94:91:7f:3a:38:94 REACHABLE
192.168.1.1 dev eno1 lladdr 94:91:7f:3a:38:94 STALE
fe80::3eec:efff:feb9:caf8 dev eno1 lladdr 3c:ec:ef:b9:ca:f8 STALE
fe80::11:bb4e:5b23:413a dev wls5 lladdr bc:d0:74:3e:36:bc STALE
fe80::4e4:a9eb:9de8:6dd6 dev wls5  FAILED
fe80::9691:7fff:fe3a:3894 dev eno1 lladdr 94:91:7f:3a:38:94 router REACHABLE
fe80::cdf:8bd3:10de:fedf dev wls5 lladdr d6:63:88:2f:99:18 STALE
```

```
HOST1$ ss -tln sport = 22
State            Recv-Q           Send-Q                      Local Address:Port                       Peer Address:Port           Process
LISTEN           0                128                               0.0.0.0:22                              0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN           0                128                                  [::]:22                                 [::]:*
```

```
HOST2$ 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:ec:ef:b9:ca:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:ec:ef:b9:ca:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 47.51.66.227/29 brd 47.51.66.231 scope global noprefixroute eno2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2600:6c84:a900:2b2::c68/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 2722sec preferred_lft 2722sec
    inet6 2600:6c84:a900:2b2:54ac:eb83:5377:6d24/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 502863sec preferred_lft 5964sec
    inet6 2600:6c84:a900:2b2:af96:2c2f:4825:ef3f/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 502863sec preferred_lft 502863sec
    inet6 fe80::343e:b7c0:7c32:d7a6/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9a:60:86:38:17:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 47.51.66.227/30 brd 47.51.66.227 scope global noprefixroute usb0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2ab8:a2b3:13eb:5d2/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:b3:fe:76:9d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:b3ff:fefe:769d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: veth5f11aad@if6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default
    link/ether 42:67:78:26:bc:e4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::4067:78ff:fe26:bce4/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
HOST2$ ip r
default via 47.51.66.225 dev eno2 proto static metric 101
default via 47.51.66.225 dev usb0 proto static metric 20100
47.51.66.224/30 dev usb0 proto kernel scope link src 47.51.66.227 metric 100
47.51.66.224/29 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 47.51.66.227 metric 101
169.254.0.0/16 dev usb0 scope link metric 1000
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
```

```
HOST2$ ip neigh
47.51.66.228 dev eno2  FAILED
47.51.66.225 dev eno2 lladdr 94:91:7f:3a:38:94 REACHABLE
47.51.66.226 dev usb0  FAILED
192.168.1.1 dev eno2 lladdr 94:91:7f:3a:38:94 STALE
47.51.66.225 dev usb0  FAILED
172.17.0.2 dev docker0 lladdr 02:42:ac:11:00:02 STALE
fe80::9691:7fff:fe3a:3894 dev eno2 lladdr 94:91:7f:3a:38:94 router STALE
```

The line `47.51.66.226 dev usb0  FAILED` looks suspicious, as that is the address for HOST1, but there is no usb ethernet connected to this machine; only eno2 should be active

```
HOST2$ ss -tln sport = 22
State            Recv-Q           Send-Q                      Local Address:Port                       Peer Address:Port           Process
LISTEN           0                128                               0.0.0.0:22                              0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN           0                128                                  [::]:22                                 [::]:*
```

Comment: On each host, use the output of `ifconfig -a; netstat -rn; arp -an` to identify whether they believe they're on the same IP subnet. The mask matters. Run `tcpdump` on host1, while on the other you execute `arp -d host1; ping host1`. Hopefully we observe an ARP broadcast from 2 asking about 1, then a reply from 1, then unicast ICMP request from 2, then ICMP echo reply from 1.

Comment: It looks like they do not have the same mask. I attempted to fix that and managed to knock one of the boxes off the internet… I will debug further when I can be there in person

Comment: Just last week I had to *make* two hosts in consecutive IP addresses deaf to each other (as a temporary workaround to a network design oops). In my case, I did it with `iptables`. If fixing the netmask does not solve the issue, check `iptables-save | less`, `arptables -L`, and `nft list ruleset`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things of note

1. You're using eno1 on host1 and eno2 on host2. Make sure you've got the ethernet cable connected to the correct ports on each host.
2. On host1 you're using `47.51.66.226/30` with a broadcast of `47.51.66.227`, but on host2 you have `47.51.66.227/29` with a broadcast of `47.51.66.231`. That's not going to work because they are different subnets.

I haven't reviewed further as these are stoppers.

Comment: The mismatch in the net masks was the problem! Thanks for this suggestion and thanks to others for suggesting things that made that discrepancy clear. This will make it easier for me to debug in the future!